# VirtualBox doesn't boot vmdk disk

Tags: virtualbox, windows-xp-mode, vmdk

I converted Windows XP mode using VMware Player and vCenter converter and it runs fine. But now I want to run it in VirtualBox and it says "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted." I went through the settings in VMware and changed the VirtualBox settings to match, but that didn't work. I tried all 3 IDE controller types, but none of them work. If I try to do a repair install of XP using a CD image it says the drive is just unallocated space. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the virtual disk still bootable from VMware Player? What version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: VMware boots it fine. I'm using version 4.1.22 of VirtualBox

Comment: Can you explain if you have a solution ?